# Keyboard shortcut to submit code commit in xcode4?

Tags: version-control, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, commit

In Xcode 4, the keyboard command to commit code is cmd+alt+c. That takes you to a comparison/comment screen.

Now, when you're done typing the comment, how do you accept the commit with the keyboard? The comment field has focus, and tabbing out of it doesn't work. Return + any combination of modifier keys also don't work, as doesn't cmd+s.

Do I *really* have to use the mouse to commit the commit, or is there a keyboard shortcut I just can't find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a numeric keyboard use Cmd+Enter as John Yeates said.

On a notebook keyboard you can use Cmd+Fn+Return to commit.

Answer (score 8):

Command+Enter (on the numeric keypad) works for me.

(Command-Return doesn't, so if you're on a keyboard without a numeric keypad, it may require some uncomfortable finger gymnastics…)

Answer (score 3):

For keyboards without numeric keypads, Function+Command+Return does the trick.

(fn+Return) == Enter

Answer (score 0):

You can also hit shift+tab 5 times to get the input focus onto the commit message field when the dialog is displayed. This plus command+enter or function+command+return lets you commit without touching the mouse.